# Pandas - How to predict values of a another column with values from neighboring columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, prediction

I have a `pandas` DataFrame that consists of several rows and columns. I am specifically interested in two columns. See the below example.

```
    UID    Item               Composition
    1      Water              Hydrogen,Oxygen
    2      Sulfuric acid      Hydrogen,Sulfur,Oxygen
    3      Alcohol            Spirit
    4      Hydrochloric acid  Hydrogen,Chloride
    5      Citric Acid        Hydrogen,Carbon, Oxygen
```

Let's say we have a very long list. I would like to predict the `Item` column by learning the `Composition` column. Please suggest the best method to do this using `python` libraries.

Comment: could you show us what have you tried till now?

Comment: I am sorry the orginial data cant be shared. But is it is same as my example above. I tried to see the correlation of most of the columns and dropped ones that I didnt see fit. I have retained only the ones I need and I see one column that is very useful to possibly predict the value of the other. In my above example, I feel by learning the composition it gets easier to predict the item. I tried to do a unstack dataframe of the two columns item and composition with df.groupby('Item')['Composition'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)

Comment: You want to perform predictions here. Please check some regression and classification algorithms online. The libraries you will need can be scikit, keras, tensorflow, to mention a few depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: With minimal changes, this can be converted into a simple classification problem. How many distinct items are in `Composition` (as we may want to categorise the column)?

Comment: There are 194 distinct items in Composition. There are around 12 items in the item column.

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be using sklearn library (decision tree classifier) as you have few features only. The composition will need to be separated and coded to numeric values. I'm not an expert in this filed, you can find plenty resources about it here and elsewhere. It helped me with similar problem to yours. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @B.Malysz for taking the time to comment and giving me a direction. I did go through the decision trees and kept on reading a lot of material and finally found that using TF-IDF vectorizer I was able to build a logic that can solve this problem. I was able to predict the item from its composition with quite a good accuracy level. I also tried to use LinearSVC, Randomforestclassifier or logisticregression and test to see which gives better prediction results.

Unfortunately I have been down voted by some people for asking this question :(